# crontab to prevent USB hard drive from spinning down

Tags: hard-drive, cron, usb-drive, dd

I want to prevent my hard drive, an internal drive externally attached via USB dock, from spinning down. I don't see any way to adjust APM through `hdparm`, so I'm assuming it's limited by the firmware of the dock. This spins up the drive:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/null count=1 skip=$RANDOM
```

But when I put the same thing in crontab via

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and

```
* * * * * dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/null count=1 skip=$RANDOM
```

nothing happens. Yes, I did check whether the drive is at `/dev/sdc`. I don't know if this info is relevant, but I've edited the crontab several times, and in each time, it suggested to save in a different file by default, which I followed. I'm not sure if this is the correct usage of `skip=$RANDOM` to read from a random block to prevent reading from cache.

Also, how can I make sure I target the correct drive persistently across several boot-ups or other orders of plugging in other devices, rather than targeting whatever ends up being `/dev/sdc`? I'm thinking something like

```
dd if=(findmnt -rn -S UUID=number_from_blkid -o SOURCE) of/dev/null count=1 skip=$RANDOM
```

but I don't know how to nest the return of the parenthetical statement into the outer statement. And even if I could, it would return `/dev/sdX2`, where `X` is whatever letter it happens to be and `2` is the only usable partition. The other is Windows reserved. This is less elegant than plain `sdX`.

Comment: AFAIK `$RANDOM` is a bashism whereas `cron` runs jobs in `sh` by default - are you sure it isn't just returning empty?

Comment: @steeldriver , I'm new to bash; got into it only due to this problem. I know that if I use the `dd` command outside of `crontab`, it will cause the drive to spin back up, even after the fact that I've added the same command to `crontab`. But [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/632412) suggests it works.

Comment: But that answer explicitly uses bash i.e. `bash -c 'dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null count=1 skip=$RANDOM'` whereas yours uses the default cron shell

Comment: @steeldriver , You're right. Prepending `bash -c` to the rest did the trick. Now, how can I do this by `UUID` rather than `/dev/sdX`? I'm basing my `findmnt` usage on [this other answer](http://serverfault.com/a/651823) and I get the UUID from `sudo blkid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problems

1. It runs using the shell `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`, so `$RANDOM` probably doesn't work
2. Unless you set the `PATH` within your `crontab` file, it won't know where things like `dd` (or in the solution below, `bash`) are located
3. If you want to do it using UUIDs, a much simpler way is to use `/dev/disk/by-uuid/THE-UUID`

### The solution

1. Find out the device file under `/dev/disk/by-uuid` by looking it up and checking that you don't get any errors with `dd` (replace `THE-UUID` with the actual UUID):

   ```
   ls -alF /dev/disk/by-uuid
   sudo dd if=/dev/disk/by-uuid/THE-UUID of=/dev/null count=1 skip=$RANDOM
   ```
2. Edit `root`'s `crontab` to (replace `THE-UUID` with the actual UUID):

   ```
   * * * * * /bin/bash -c 'dd if=/dev/disk/by-uuid/THE-UUID of=/dev/null count=1 skip=$RANDOM'
   ```

Comment: I have to wait out the firmware's idle-time-limit to spin down, to see if this doesn't spin down. The USB docked drive partition's UUID is alphanumeric but not dash-separated like that of my internally connected hard drive's partitions. In [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/651823), the example's UUID is dash-separated. Is this going to be a problem?

Comment: I think NTFS drives (and perhaps other file systems too) are alphanumeric without dashes. See the [UsingUUID page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID#Finding_UUIDs) for an example of that happening.

Comment: When I do your first step to see that I don't get any errors, the output shows it writes 512 bytes. But this is an advanced format 4 KiB sector drive. Is this a problem? Should I include `bs=4096` right before the `count=1`?

Comment: I don't think you'll need it because reading only 512 bytes at a time is supported just fine by `dd` and by drives, even if the sector size is different. What will happen is that, if the drive only supports 4096-byte reads, Linux will read in that and hand the first 512 bytes over to `dd`, so you effectively get the right behavior for free.

Comment: Oh, I see. And I meant to say "reads 512 bytes from the hard drive" instead of "writes 512 bytes" in my previous comment (but I presume it does write to `/dev/null`), but you got my meaning. I was just basing my comment off of the terminal output that prints `512 bytes (512 B) copied`.

Comment: FYI: To add this root cron job I used the standard for root's crontab `sudo crontab -e`